# Remove empty items from preg_split result array

Tags: php, preg-split

I am trying to clear a string of `" "` , `,` , `.` , `?` , `!` but the result array contains an empty element.

My code:

```
$mesaj = "Ana are mere, dar nu are si nuci? Matei are nuci!";
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,.?!]+/", $mesaj);
print_r($keywords);
```

The output is as follows:

```
Array (
    [0] => Ana
    [1] => are
    [2] => mere
    [3] => dar
    [4] => nu 
    [5] => are
    [6] => si
    [7] => nuci
    [8] => Matei
    [9] => are
    [10] => nuci
    [11] => 
)
```

I want to remove the empty elements from the above array. How can this be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` flag:

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\s,.?!]+/", $mesaj, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

The `-1` in the above statement is to enable the use of flags. See the [documentation for `preg_split()`](https://www.php.net/preg_split) for more information.

[**Online demo**](https://eval.in/104692)

Comment: But it does not work:( It echoes this: Array ( [0] => Ana are mere, dar nu are si nuci? Matei are nuci! )

Comment: @Filip: Are you sure you're seeing the latest version of the answer? I've updated the answer to include a working demo.